# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProperties() on null in W:\domains\Shop.loc\public\index.php

Tags: php

Registry.php

```php
    namespace shop;

      use TSingleton;

    class Registry {


        public  static $properties = [];

        public function setProperty($name, $value){
            self::$properties[$name] = $value;
        }

        public function  getProperty($name){
            if(isset(self::$properties[$name])){
                return self::$proporties[$name];
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        }


        public function getProperties(){
            return self::$properties;
        }
    }
```

index.php

```php
     require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/init.php';

     new \shop\App();
     var_dump(\shop\App::$app->getProperties());
```

TSingleton.php

```php
    namespace shop;

    trait TSingletone{

        private static $instance;

        public static function instance(){
            if (self :: $instance === null){
                self::$instance = new self;
            };
            return self::$instance;
        }

    }
```

params.php

```php
    return [

      'admin_email' => 'admin.com', 
      'shop_name' => 'Shop.loc',
      'pagination' => 3,
      'smtp_login' => 'ddada',
      'smtp_password' => 'adad',


    ];
```

App.php

```php
    namespace shop;

      class App {

        public static $app;

        public function construct(){
            $query = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/');
            self::$app = Registry::instance();
            $this -> getParams();
        }

        protected function getParams(){
            $params = require_once CONF . '/params.php';
            if (!empty($params)){
                foreach ($params as $k => $v){
                    self::$app->setProperty($k , $v);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Опять вопрос из серии "угадай мой сон, изучив портянку битого кода"... :( Встречный вопрос: зачем включать в код своего вопроса трейт `TSingletone`, если он в коде _нигде не используется_? И при этом не включать код из файла config/init.php, хотя _он-то как раз - выполняется_?

Answer (score 2):

Cделай выполнение через `try`, а в `catch` закинь всевозможную отладочную инфу и смотри что не так.

```
try{
     require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/init.php';

     new \shop\App();
     var_dump(\shop\App::$app->getProperties());
}catch(Error $e){
     var_dump($e,debug_backtrace(),get_included_files());exit;
}
```

Хотя тут и без дебага невооруженным глазом видно, что `App -> getParams()` нигде не выполняется, потому что метод `App -> construct()` - не меджик, и не был вызван нигде в коде!

Answer (score 2):

Перенесите запись use TSingleton; внутрь класса Registry. У Вас не правильный синтаксис использования тейтов.